# Procurar valor em array com índice multinível ou não

Tags: php

Tenho 2 arrays:

Um com o índice `cod` multinível e outro não:

```
$array1 = array(
        0 => array("item" => 101010, "cod" => 70),
        1 => array("item" => 102010, "cod" => 80),
        2 => array("item" => 103010, "cod" => 90)
        );

$array2 = array(
        0 => array("item" => 104010, "cod" => array
            (0 => 70, 1 => 80, 2 => 90)),
        1 => array("item" => 105010, "cod" => 80),
        2 => array("item" => 106010, "cod" => 70)
        );
```

**Impresso:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 101010
            [cod] => 70
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 102010
            [cod] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 103010
            [cod] => 90
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item] => 104010
            [cod] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 70
                    [1] => 80
                    [2] => 90
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item] => 105010
            [cod] => 80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item] => 106010
            [cod] => 70
        )

)
```

Quando uso o `array_search` com o `array_column`, ele **não irá trazer** o valor **caso for multinível**:

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $v) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $v['item'] .' - '. array_search($v['cod'], array_column($array2,'cod'));
}
```

**Saída:**

```
101010 - 2
102010 - 1
103010 -
```

Existe alguma **função nativa** que faça essa busca considerando ele ser multinível ou não ?

Caso não, como poderia fazer para tratar ?

Comment: Isso, basta adaptar a lógica da função anônima em `array_filter`.

Comment: @W.Faustino funciona com multidimensional ou não, no mesmo filtro ?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss funciona com as 2 estruturas com esse `array_filter` ?

Comment: É fazer a função para funcionar. Algo como "se for array, procura com in_array, se não, verifica se é igual".